# How can I get ArrayAdapter strings from string resources?

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I have an `ArrayAdapter<String>` that I am using to show a single choice `Dialog` like this:

```
dialogBuilder.setAdapter(arrayAdapter ...
```

This is the `ArrayAdapter`:

```
arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(StartActivity.this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice);
arrayAdapter.addAll("A Tropical Rainforest", "Backwater Chorus", "Big River", "Bird Song 1", "Bird Song 2", "Cave Ambience", "Cold Stormy Wind",
            "Crickets", "Deep Woods", "Fireplace", "Jungle River", "Long Soothing Rain", "Ocean Waves 1", "Ocean Waves 2",
            "Pacific And Songbirds", "Pig Frogs", "Small Green Froggies", "Small Rapid", "Sparkling Water", "Stormy Wind",
            "Thunder and Rain", "Thunderstorm Inner Perspective", "Twilight", "Waterfall", "Wind");
```

Now the problem is that I want to make this a multi language app which means I need to get all of this strings from String Resources. But I can't do it since a String Resource returns `int` while I can only insert `String` in there.

Any idea how I can do this?

Comment: Create a resource id array that corresponds with the strings you need and add the strings dynamically from the array using getResources().getString(resourceArray[pos]) in some sort of loop

Comment: Haha this is why you should read an entire question, I thought you were saying you needed access to int ids. Sigh haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an array resource

```
<resources>
    <string-array name="values">
        <item>A Tropical Rainforest</item>
        <item>Backwater Chorus</item>
        <item>Big River</item>
        <item>Bird Song 1</item>
        <item>And so on</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

And now, you can retrieve the values from code like this:

```
 String values[] = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.values);
 arrayAdapter.addAll(values);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, define a string array in resources:

```
<string-array name="nature_things_array">
    <item>A Tropical Rainforest</item>
    <item>Backwater Chorus</item>
    <item>Big River</item>
    <item>Bird Song 1</item>
</string-array>
```

Then set single choice items to `AlertDialog.Builder`:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
builder.setTitle(R.string.pick_color)
       .setMultiChoiceItems(R.array.nature_things_array, null,
                  new DialogInterface.OnSingleChoiceClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which,
                   boolean isChecked) {
               // ...
           }
       })
});
return builder.create();
```

You can find a good android dialog manual [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html).